# VTK Stereo with (Nvidia RTX A5000 GPU and DLP projectors)

Tags: c++, windows, 3d, nvidia, vtk

## Outline

I have a workstation with two RTXA5000 connected via a **NVIDIA Quadro Sync II**. With the graphics cards I control **3 Optoma CinemaX D2 projectors** (4K 60Hz). I connect each graphics card with a **8k DPI (GPU) to HDMI(Projector) cable**. The goal is to view 3D content on the DLP capable projectors with **3D shutter glasses**. The glasses are capable with 90Hz/100Hz 120Hz/144Hz. I have the problem that I do not perceive any 3D effect. I suspect that the Hz of the Beamer does not match that of the 3D glasses. I'm having trouble figuring out where (**Nvidia Control Panel**, **Windows11**) and what values to set?

#Setup
*Note: I have tested different resolutions and refresh rates - in this example I use the lowest resolution the projector can manage for 3D to avoid any problems with too low refresh rates. For simplicity i also use only one projector*

The 4K projectors are set in Windows (see image) to 1280x720 (3D) and the check mark in W11 for 3D is set. The refresh rate is set to 29.97Hz. With that alone i do not get a 3D effect (i.e., viewing with the shutter glasses gives no 3D effect). In the vtk application i can see that there is a flickering (left/right image). You can also see that in the image the Desktop mode hast the desired resolution and refresh rate BUT there is a active signal mode which is 3840x2160, 29,97Hz. The Beamer also displays that its set to 3840x2160, 30Hz. I also set stereo to ON and selected generic active stereo in the global 3D settings in the Nvidia Control Panel. Changing the resolution in the Nvidia Control Panel results in a reset back to the old resolution.

[image: 1: Windows Refresh Rate]
[image: 2: Nvidia Resolution]

## VTK

I am testing with a **VTK(c++)** application from which i know it would yield a 3D effect. For this i enable the Stereo options of the *RenderWindow* and set the mode to *VTK_STEREO_CRYSTAL_EYES*. I display a basic cylinder through the stereo window.

```
...
    vtkNew<vtkRenderer> renderer;
    renderer->AddActor(cylinderActor);    
...
    renderWindow->SetSize(300, 300);
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renderWindow->SetStereoCapableWindow(true);
    renderWindow->SetStereoRender(true);
    renderWindow->SetStereoType(VTK_STEREO_CRYSTAL_EYES);
    renderWindow->StereoUpdate();
...
```

Depending of the refresh rate of the projector i can see the flickering.
I do not find any code to access the resolution and refresh rate of external devices, in my case the projectors, to sync the refresh rate of the vtk rendering with the projectors.

## Question

I suspect the problem is the refresh rate and the difference between projector and desktop/VTK. Therefore, is there a way to **set the resolution and refresh rate in VTK** (for the projectors and the rendering)? Or can I **access the graphics card via code** and fix these settings?